# IBM website zoomed in too far in various browsers

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, firefox-for-android, zooming, samsung-internet-browser

*Android 11; Samsung Galaxy A20 (SM-S205G)*

---

I've had a long-standing problem on my Android phone with *IBM Community forum websites*.

Forum postings [like this one](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/iot/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=4573&MessageKey=06b719ab-8f1d-4bee-aecd-eb3db343d4b7&CommunityKey=60718772-c63c-4d74-bdad-56d8beac4ba3&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2Fcommunity%2Fuser%2Fiot%2Fcommunities%2Fcommunity-home%2Fdigestviewer%3Fcommunitykey%3D60718772-c63c-4d74-bdad-56d8beac4ba3%26tab%3Ddigestviewer) are zoomed in too far. I can't read the text on either side of the page (portrait or landscape).

I have the same problem in all browsers that I've tried. I've tried pinching out the screen to zoom out, but that doesn't do anything. It stays at the same zoom level.

- [Samsung Internet 15.0.2.47](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xou6l.png)
- [Firefox 92.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV4Lq.png)
- [Chrome 93.0.4577.62](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBeGV.png)

My uneducated guess would be that the page isn't handling responsive design properly. I've reported the problem to IBM. But they don't seem to be interested in fixing it.

I don't have this problem with any other websites on my Android phone. For example, there are even other [IBM forums that don't have this problem](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ailearning/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=5059&MessageKey=e123e131-56e0-4c5d-9f5a-f68fd9f3c087&CommunityKey=d388e552-3a57-460d-911b-8da3b9e1e497&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2Fcommunity%2Fuser%2Failearning%2Fhome). But unfortunately, I don't use those specific forums.

---

I've had some luck solving the issue on a different device: Safari/iPad (7th gen; 17.7.1).

In Safari, there is an option where I can zoom out at a set percentage (85%).

[image]

[That works well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaHgG.png) There's a tiny bit of cutoff at the righthand side. But I can live with that.

---

**Question:**

To compensate for the problem with the IBM website on my phone, is there a way for me to change the zoom level in an Android browser app? (just like I did with Safari?)

So far, I haven't found a setting like that in Samsung Internet, Firefox, or Chrome. I'm open to installing a different browser on my phone if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are open to trying other browsers, install [Opera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser) and open the site in it. Next, tap on the  symbol with letter A (circled in screen shot below) and the content is rendered legibly in *Reader Mode*

[image]

If you are comfortable viewing in desktop mode, that also works.

Edit: If you want to use Chrome and are fine with Safari like experience, from Settings → Accessibility → Text scaling adjust the slider to increase/decrease font size and view the site in *desktop mode*. The last word of every sentence is clipped though.